# Acquiring and storing accelerometer data on Android Wear smartwatch

Tags: java, android-activity, android-service, wear-os, android-sensors

I'm trying to acquire accelerometer data using an Android Wear app on a smartwatch (Samsung Gear Live). To acquire that data I use a service which listens to three components:

1. a SensorEventListener, where the onSensorChanged method triggers a SensorEventLoggerTask that stores the accelerometer data with timestamps in a file on the smartwatch
2. a System intent that listens to the battery
3. an Intent that listens button clicks on an activity.  The activity is used to annotate the data, so I have an idea at what timestamp an (person)activity (running, eating, sleeping,...) was started:

This works fine and I can sample the data every (more or less) 5-6 ms.  However this only works when the smartwatch is connected through adb or when the activity is active (to press a button).  From the moment it is not connected anymore, there are gaps in the data.  With gaps I mean that the time between two timestamps of accelerometer values is much larger than the 5-6 ms.  Going to seconds... The gaps appear irregular.  But when the activity becomes active (to press a button) or I connect the smartwatch to the adb, the values are gathered.  It appears that the service is paused/sleeps/shut down, when the smartwatch is not active.

Below I post the code.  The project consists of two classes WearableActivity and WearableService.  Furthermore, I also show the Manifest.  Allthough this is only prototyping code, any help in resolving the data gaps or suggestions to the code, would be greatly appreciated.

**WearableActivity.java**

```
public class WearableActivity extends Activity {

//Set strings and widgets
private static final String TAG = "WearableActivity";

private TextView mTextView;
private Button[] buttons;
private String[] strings;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //setscreen
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wearable);

    //check if service is already running
    if(this.check() == false)
        this.startService(new Intent(this, WearableService.class));

    Resources res = this.getResources();
    strings = res.getStringArray(R.array.button_names);
    buttons = new Button[strings.length];

    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
            mTextView.setText("ActiMon_Store Started");
            buttons[0] = (Button)stub.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            buttons[1] = (Button)stub.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            buttons[2] = (Button)stub.findViewById(R.id.button3);
            buttons[3] = (Button)stub.findViewById(R.id.button4);

            buttons[0].setText(strings[0]);
            buttons[1].setText(strings[1]);
            buttons[2].setText(strings[2]);
            buttons[3].setText(strings[3]);
            for(Button b : buttons)
                    b.setOnClickListener(btnListener);
        }
    });
}


//---create an anonymous class to act as a button click listener---
private OnClickListener btnListener = new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {   
        Intent buttonIntent = new Intent("button_activity");
        Button b = (Button)v;
        buttonIntent.putExtra("time", Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        buttonIntent.putExtra("button", b.getText().toString());
        sendBroadcast(buttonIntent);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                "Event sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   } 
};  
//Checks is the service WearableService already started
    public boolean check(){
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) 
        {
            if ("com.example.WearableService"
                    .equals(service.service.getClassName())) 
            {
                Log.i(TAG,"Service already running!");
                return true;
            }
        }
        Log.i(TAG,"Service already running!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

**WearableService.java**

```
public class WearableService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {


private PrintStream ps;
private PrintStream ps_bat;
private PrintStream ps_button;
private String androidpath;

private float[] gravity = new float[3];
private float[] linear_acceleration = new float[3];

private PowerManager pm;
private PowerManager.WakeLock wl;

private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mAcceleroSensor;

//Create the service and register the listeners
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    this.registerListeners();
}

//Registers the SensorManager, the listener to the battery and the intent
private void registerListeners(){
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAcceleroSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
mSensorManager.registerListener(this,mAcceleroSensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

    IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    Intent batteryStatus = this.registerReceiver(battery_receiver, ifilter);
    this.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("button_activity"));
}

//Start service as at STICKY
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    this.getFile();

    pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK |
                                              PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | 
                                              PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,"KeepCPUWorking");
    wl.acquire();

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

//When sensor value has changed
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
    if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){

        //Perform a background task to store the data
        new SensorEventLoggerTask().execute(event);

        }
}

 //Get handles to files where data has to be stored
 public void getFile(){
        androidpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        try{
            ps = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(androidpath + "/data_acc.dat"));
            ps_bat = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(androidpath + "/data_bat.dat"));
            ps_button = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(androidpath + "/data_button.dat"));
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }

//Create receiver that listens to Intents from the Battery
 private BroadcastReceiver battery_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
         int bLevel = arg1.getIntExtra("level", -1); // gets the battery level
         int bScale = arg1.getIntExtra("scale", -1);
         ps_bat.println("" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ";" + bLevel + ";" + bScale);
     } 
 };

 @Override
 public void onDestroy(){
     if(wl.isHeld()) wl.release();

 }

   // For receiving the broadcast event of the buttons.
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new 
        BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {             
            String msg = intent.getStringExtra("button") + ";" + intent.getStringExtra("time");
            ps_button.println(msg);

        }
    };

//Create a Task that logs events to a file
 private class SensorEventLoggerTask extends AsyncTask<SensorEvent, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(SensorEvent... events) {
        //Getting the event and values
        SensorEvent event = events[0];
        String msg = "" + event.values[0] + ";" + event.values[1] + ";" + event.values[2];
         //constructing the the line
         msg = "" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ";" + msg;

         //writing to file
         ps.println(msg);
        return null;
    }
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.wearabledemo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="20"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS" />
<uses-permission   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >
    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".WearableActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name=".WearableService"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" >
       </service>


</application>

</manifest>`
```

Comment: That's indeed an interesting problem, and I just might have to solve it as well. If I cross with a nice solution, I'll post it as an answer.